# How to find Kmeans total number of iterations?

Tags: matlab, k-means

I am working on k-means algorithm. I have applied k-means algorithm using inbuilt function of statistical tool box.I have applied it on big data. I want to know the number of total iterations taken by the function to partition the data into final clusters! I am not a usual user of MATLAB. Please help me in finding the number of iterations.

Comment: Please update your question to include your code, see [mcve]. I guess you're using the [`kmeans`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) function, read the documentation; it's capable of displaying the number of iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Name, Value` inputs to [kmeans](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html):

```
idx = kmeans(X,k,Name,Value)
```

Specifically, `'Display','final'` or `'Display','iter'` as shown [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html#namevaluepairarguments).

You can see an example of the output from [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html#buefthh-2):

```
opts = statset('Display','final');
[idx,C] = kmeans(X,2,'Distance','cityblock',...
    'Replicates',5,'Options',opts);

Replicate 1, 4 iterations, total sum of distances = 201.533.
Replicate 2, 6 iterations, total sum of distances = 201.533.
Replicate 3, 4 iterations, total sum of distances = 201.533.
Replicate 4, 4 iterations, total sum of distances = 201.533.
Replicate 5, 3 iterations, total sum of distances = 201.533.
Best total sum of distances = 201.533
```